# How to Make Destination Workbook Dynamic When Moving Data From Another User Selected File Using A VBA Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm attempting to have a user select a file, then through a `UserForm` select the worksheet they want to copy from.

The issue is on this line: `ReportWbk.Sheets(ws).Cells.Copy Destination:=TargetWbk.Sheets("Test Import").Cells(1, 1)`

I have confirmed that the file, worksheet selection, and copy function all work as expected.  I get a `run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.` which to me means that the code is looking for the destination sheet in the workbook that the user selected (the 'target' file).  Since it doesn't exist there, it errors out.

I'm wondering how to fix this dynamically so that the code will work without naming the workbook specifically.  I might run this with other workbooks open and in different workbooks.

I verified that `workbooks("WorkbookName").Sheets("Test Import").Cells(1, 1)` works as I want but I'm looking to make the "WorkbookName" part dynamic / automatically select the workbook that the macro was run from.

The main code is directly below and the userform code is below that in case that's part of the issue:

```
Private Sub GetRange()
  Dim ReportWbk As Workbook 'workbook with report data
  Dim Report As Integer 'name of file with report data
  Dim FD As FileDialog
  Dim TargetWbk As Workbook 'this workbook
  Dim ws As Variant

  Set TargetWbk = ThisWorkbook
  Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  Report = FD.Show
'cancel pressed
    If Report <> -1 Then Exit Sub
'open selected workbook
    Set ReportWbk = Workbooks.Open(FD.SelectedItems(1))
   ws = SelectSheet.Selection(ReportWbk)
'cancel pressed
     If ws = vbCancel Then GoTo exitsub
    ReportWbk.Sheets(ws).Cells.Copy Destination:=TargetWbk.Sheets("Test Import").Cells(1, 1)

exitsub:
    ReportWbk.Close False
     'changes the color of the destination worksheet tab
     Worksheets("Test Import").Tab.Color = RGB(25, 25, 25)
 
End Sub
```

UserForm Code:

```
    Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
     Me.Tag = Me.ListBox1.Value
    Me.Hide
End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Tag = vbCancel
    Me.Hide
End Sub


Function Selection(ByVal wb As Object) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
'add all sheets to listbox
         Me.ListBox1.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
 'default - select first sheet in list
        With Me.ListBox1
             .ListIndex = 0
             .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
        End With
    Me.Show
'return result
    Selection = Me.Tag
    Unload Me
End Function


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Caption = "Select Sheet"
    Me.CmdOK.Caption = "OK"
    Me.cmdCancel.Caption = "Cancel"
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'disable X closing form
    Cancel = CBool(CloseMode = 0)
    If Cancel = -1 Then Me.Tag = vbCancel: Me.Hide  
End Sub
```

I know this is a simple thing but I've been away from VBA for a few years and rusty as heck.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose `ws = SelectSheet.Selection(ReportWbk)` causes ws to hold an error instead of a sheet since `SelectSheet` is not defined as anything, if you'd want to use your function `Selection(ReportWbk)` you can just type it as such. Not a big fan myself calling subs/functions/variables to collections and the such. I always think "you wouldn't use For in the For loop either like `For for = 1 To lRow` but maybe that's just me, I just don't like to run into syntax issues.

Comment: @Notus_Panda That doesn't surprise me that the issue is related to the interaction between the UserForm and the main Sub.  I haven't used this structure much at all before.  I tried using ``ws=Selection` and `ws=Selection(Reportwbk)` but neither resolved the issue.  Since naming the workbook resolves the error (replacing `TargetWbk.Sheets("Test Import").Cells(1, 1)` with `workbooks("WorkbookName").Sheets("Test Import").Cells(1, 1)`) , wouldn't the issue be related the `Set TargetWbk = ThisWorkbook` ?

Comment: The issue iirc from my testing yesterday, is that you can't open the desired workbook, fill in the listbox with the sheet names, let the user select the ones he wants and copy the data all at once. You need at least one button to let the user choose the workbook and then it fills in the sheets in the listbox. Then another button to create what you want from the chosen sheets.